How to resolve architecture incompatibility errors when building Qt from source on Windows 10?
I have been trying to install Qt on my Windows 10 laptop. I originally downloaded the online installer and used it to get Qt and Qt Creator, but I was not able to add a plugin that I needed: QtSQL: mysql.
Hence, now I have changed to trying to build from the source code, I am using v6.8.0-beta1 tag for the source code download. I needed it to ensure that I get init-repository.bat, so I can stick to Windows build environments.
So I have tried to make it work, I have the environment set up: CMake, Ninja, MSVC 2022, MSVC 2019 and MinGW. MinGW is from GitHub — niXman — mingw-builds-binaries — Release of 13.2.0-rt_v11-rev1; File x86_64-13.2.0-release-win32-seh-msvcrt-rt_v11-rev0.7z. This has given me version 13.2.0 for MinGW.
I have also set up both MSVC 2022 and 2019 with amd64, so they have the build environment of x64.
To build, I ran this command:
git clone --branch v6.8.0-beta1 code.qt.io/qt/qt5.git Qt

Then:
configure -init-submodules

When I try to run cmake --build, both with and without --parallel, it gives me this error:
C:\Qt>cmake --build .
[26/11645] Linking CXX executable qtbase\bin\syncqt.exe
FAILED: qtbase/bin/syncqt.exe
C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /C "cd . && C:\MinGW\bin\c++.exe -DNDEBUG -O3 -fexceptions  qtbase/src/tools/syncqt/CMakeFiles/syncqt.dir/syncqt_resource.rc.obj qtbase/src/tools/syncqt/CMakeFiles/syncqt.dir/main.cpp.obj qtbase/src/tools/syncqt/CMakeFiles/syncqt.dir/syncqt_longpath.rc.obj -o qtbase\bin\syncqt.exe -Wl,--out-implib,qtbase\src\tools\syncqt\libsyncqt.dll.a -Wl,--major-image-version,0,--minor-image-version,0  -lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lwinspool -lshell32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -luuid -lcomdlg32 -ladvapi32 && cd ."
C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: i386 architecture of input file `qtbase/src/tools/syncqt/CMakeFiles/syncqt.dir/syncqt_resource.rc.obj' is incompatible with i386:x86-64 output
C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: i386 architecture of input file `qtbase/src/tools/syncqt/CMakeFiles/syncqt.dir/syncqt_longpath.rc.obj' is incompatible with i386:x86-64 output
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
[43/11645] Building C object qtbase/src/3rdparty/libjpeg/CMakeFiles/BundledLibjpeg.dir/jdhuff.c.obj
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.

How can I get the Qt mysql driver to work either with the beta build or any other way on Windows 10 x64 to work?
Previous Tries:

I had originally downloaded from the online installer with qt 6.7.2. I tried to initialize the MySQL drivers from various ways, first from the MySQL c++ connector. That didn't work, I tried to do it with the Qt SQL driver but that was not working because for some reason, probably because Qt\----\mingw\plugins\sqldrivers was empty.
I tried again with 6.5.3 and it still still didn't work.
I tried with 6.6.3 and sqldrivers was not empty this time. The initialization of MySQL following C:\Qt\6.0.0\Src\configure.bat -sql-mysql -- -DMySQL_INCLUDE_DIR="C:\mysql-8.0.22-winx64\include" -DMySQL_LIBRARY="C:\mysql-8.0.22-winx64\lib\libmysql.lib" worked, but then the build process did not work no matter which MinGW I used.
I did next time from source with v6.6.0. init-repository with perl and build was again not working.

After these, I thought it might be due to the environment, so I tried to do it without perl which is only in the dev branch and in v6.8.0-beta1 which contains init-repository.bat which I thought might have been the solutions to my problems as I found on another post that perl has its own environment. And then I am here after ensuring that I have the right basic environment, or so I assume.
Update:
I removed 6.8.0-beta1 and downloaded 6.7.2. Ran perl init-repository and cmake --build . --parallel followed with cmake --install ..
Initially, I tried to initialize the sql driver using
configure.bat -sql-mysql -- -DMySQL_INCLUDE_DIR="C:\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\include" -DMySQL_LIBRARY="C:\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib\libmysql.lib"

and
call "C:\Qt\6.7.2\qtbase\bin\qt-cmake.bat" C:\Qt\6.7.2\qtbase\src\plugins\sqldrivers -DMySQL_INCLUDE_DIR="C:\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\include" -DMySQL_LIBRARY="C:\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib\libmysql.lib"

Neither worked, the second command gave me this error as part of it's output:
CMake Error at qtbase/cmake/QtBuildInformation.cmake:522 (message):
  Feature "sql_mysql": Forcing to "ON" breaks its condition:

      MySQL_FOUND

  Condition values dump:

      MySQL_FOUND = "FALSE"

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  qtbase/cmake/QtFeature.cmake:322 (qt_configure_add_report_error)
  qtbase/cmake/QtFeature.cmake:442 (qt_feature_check_and_save_internal_value)
  qtbase/cmake/QtFeature.cmake:711 (qt_evaluate_feature)
  qtbase/src/plugins/sqldrivers/CMakeLists.txt:44 (qt_feature_module_end)


-- Configuring submodule 'qtimageformats'
-- Check if compiler accepts -pthread
-- Check if compiler accepts -pthread - yes
CMake Error at qtbase/lib/cmake/Qt6BuildInternals/QtBuildInternalsExtra.cmake:151 (set):
  Syntax error in cmake code at

    C:/Qt/6.7.2/qtbase/lib/cmake/Qt6BuildInternals/QtBuildInternalsExtra.cmake:151

  when parsing string

    MySQL_INCLUDE_DIR=C:\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\include;MySQL_LIBRARY=C:\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib\libmysql.lib

  Invalid character escape '\M'.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  qtbase/lib/cmake/Qt6BuildInternals/Qt6BuildInternalsConfig.cmake:11 (include)
  qtbase/lib/cmake/Qt6/Qt6Config.cmake:169 (find_package)
  qtimageformats/CMakeLists.txt:14 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
CMake Error at qtbase/cmake/QtProcessConfigureArgs.cmake:1077 (message):
  CMake exited with code 1.

After this as I mentioned, I ran a simple configure. I can't find any mysql in the build directory.
Update 2:
I reran the first command configure.bat -sql-mysql -- -DMySQL_INCLUDE_DIR="C:\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\include" -DMySQL_LIBRARY="C:\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib\libmysql.lib".
When I ran cmake --build . --parallel I got the following error log:
C:\Qt\6.7.2>cmake --build . --parallel
[2/2163] Building RC object qtbase/src/plugins/sqldrivers/mysql/CMakeFiles/QMYSQLDriverPlugin.dir/QMYSQLDriverPlugin_resource.rc.obj
FAILED: qtbase/src/plugins/sqldrivers/mysql/CMakeFiles/QMYSQLDriverPlugin.dir/QMYSQLDriverPlugin_resource.rc.obj
C:\MinGW\bin\windres.exe -O coff -DMINGW_HAS_SECURE_API=1 -DNOMINMAX -DQMYSQLDriverPlugin_EXPORTS -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS -DQT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_UP_TO=0x040800 -DQT_EXPLICIT_QFILE_CONSTRUCTION_FROM_PATH -DQT_LEAN_HEADERS=1 -DQT_NO_AS_CONST -DQT_NO_CAST_FROM_ASCII -DQT_NO_CAST_TO_ASCII -DQT_NO_CONTEXTLESS_CONNECT -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_NO_EXCEPTIONS -DQT_NO_FOREACH -DQT_NO_JAVA_STYLE_ITERATORS -DQT_NO_NARROWING_CONVERSIONS_IN_CONNECT -DQT_NO_QEXCHANGE -DQT_PLUGIN -DQT_SQL_LIB -DQT_USE_QSTRINGBUILDER -DQT_WARN_DEPRECATED_UP_TO=0x070000 -DUNICODE -DWIN32 -DWIN64 -D_ENABLE_EXTENDED_ALIGNED_STORAGE -D_UNICODE -D_WIN64 -I C:/Qt/6.7.2/qtbase/src/plugins/sqldrivers/mysql/QMYSQLDriverPlugin_autogen/include -I C:/Qt/6.7.2/qtbase/src/plugins/sqldrivers/mysql -I C:/Qt/6.7.2/qtbase/include -I C:/Qt/6.7.2/qtbase/include/QtCore -I C:/Qt/6.7.2/qtbase/mkspecs/win32-g++ -I C:/Qt/6.7.2/qtbase/src/corelib -I C:/Qt/6.7.2/qtbase/include/QtCore/6.7.2 -I C:/Qt/6.7.2/qtbase/include/QtCore/6.7.2/QtCore -I C:/Qt/6.7.2/qtbase/src/sql -I C:/Qt/6.7.2/qtbase/include/QtSql/6.7.2 -I C:/Qt/6.7.2/qtbase/include/QtSql/6.7.2/QtSql -I C:/Qt/6.7.2/qtbase/include/QtSql -I "C:/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/include"  C:/Qt/6.7.2/qtbase/src/plugins/sqldrivers/mysql/QMYSQLDriverPlugin_resource.rc qtbase/src/plugins/sqldrivers/mysql/CMakeFiles/QMYSQLDriverPlugin.dir/QMYSQLDriverPlugin_resource.rc.obj
cc1.exe: fatal error: Server\: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
cc1.exe: fatal error: 8.0/include: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
C:\MinGW\bin\windres.exe: preprocessing failed.
[19/2163] Building CXX object qtbase/src/plugins/platforms/direct2d/CMakeFiles/QWindowsDirect2DIntegrationPlugin.dir/__/windows/qwindowsdialoghelpers.cpp.obj
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.

In case anyone else comes here, I managed to solve it: Qt Forum - Qt Installation issues on windows

You could probably just install all of this with msys2 and not have to build anything from source. What are all of the steps you've taken to build the code so far?

Ran this command: git clone --branch v6.8.0-beta1 https://code.qt.io/qt/qt5.git Qt.
Then: configure -init-submodules    .
When I try to run cmake --build .
Both with and without --parallel, it give me this error

please [edit] updates into the question. Any reason you're using a beta rather than a proper, tested, release?

Before trying to build the whole Qt from scratch, I'd try to solve the original issue: install the sql driver. You only wrote that you were not able to "add the plugin": what did you try? Have you checked the SQL Database Drivers page? Besides, as Alan noted above, you should avoid using a beta, unless you're experienced enough and you're aware of its possible limitations.

@AlanBirtles I have updated the question with all my pervious tried and why I ended up on v6.8.0-beta1, should I try again with 6.7.2?

@ajitest I still don't see any valid attempt to follow the recommended procedures (including, possibly, building the drivers on your own). Have you actually studied and followed what linked above? Also, there's no point in asking if you should try, just try it.

@musicamante I did it again with 6.7.2, I hv updated the question post again, how do I proceed?
